# Smoothly animating a header

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I'm trying to make something similar to one of those headers that reduces in size and has an element slide when the page starts scrolling down. The difference is that most of those kinds of headers that I've seen have a single large header with a background-color, and my client wants the logo to be in a separate space to the nav-bar. There's a blank space at the top with just the logo in it, then there's the nav-bar which has a background-color. So I'm trying to make the nav-bar stick to the top on scroll and slide the logo into a different position. I've tried animations and transitions but it's still really jarring on scroll.

Here's some current code that uses jQuery to add css classes on scroll, then positions the elements differently. I'm actually using sass and haven't changed it to regular css.

Html:

```
<header>
<a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png" width="170" height="68" /></a>
<nav>
<ol>
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
<li><a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
</ol>
</nav>
</header>
```

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 80){
$('nav').addClass("scroll");
$('header img').addClass("logoScroll");
}
else{
$('nav').removeClass("scroll");
$('header img').removeClass("logoScroll");
}
});
```

SASS:

```
header{
 width: 100%;
img{
margin-left:68%;
}}

 nav{
 padding:5px;
 z-index:2;
 background:#571189;
 font-size:1.3em;
 }

.scroll {
position:fixed;
top:0;
width:100%;
}

.logoScroll{
position:fixed;
top:0;
right:4%;
z-index:3;
zoom:0.6;
transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
```

Comment: your code is working fine for me . Hope you added jquery plugin and closed your `<script>` tag properly

Comment: It works well enough. It's just not a smooth movement. It looks bad because it's a bit jarring rather than smooth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For smooth transition of header and image/logo, what you have to do is, bind those tags to Jquery Scroll event and add and remove classes accordingly.

[**Check this fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/u5wjuqru/1/)

For smooth logo transition, try to use CSS3 translate property with some transition.

**Sample HTML**

```
<header>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/100/50">
    <h4>Scroll below</h4>
</header>
```

**Sample CSS**

```
header{
    padding:20px;
    background:#111; 
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.35s;
       -moz-transition: all 0.35s;
            transition: all 0.35s;}

.nav-collapse{
    padding:0}

img{
    -webkit-transition: all 0.35s;
       -moz-transition: all 0.35s;
            transition: all 0.35s;
    float:left}

img.translate{
    -ms-transform: translate(250px,0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(250px,0px);
            transform: translate(250px,0px)}

h4{color:#FFFFFF; float:right:display:inline-block}
```

**Sample Jquery**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($("header").offset().top > 50) {
        $("header").addClass("nav-collapse");
        $("img").addClass("translate");
   } else {
        $("header").removeClass("nav-collapse");
        $("img").removeClass("translate");
    }
});
```

[**Updated fiddle - another variant**](https://jsfiddle.net/u5wjuqru/4/)

Comment: That's not quite right. My page has a blank space at the top of the page and the colored background if the nav-bar slides up then stops when it gets to the top. And the logo slides over. The fixed positioning on the header stops the transitions from working at all. I tried a jsFiddle but it didn't work at all. Will have another look at yours.

Comment: Hopefully [link](https://jsfiddle.net/9c5dwt6d/) this is the JsFiddle I set up[/link]. Keep in mind, it doesn't work how it's supposed to. The JS doesn't seem to be triggering, it's just scrolling as normal and not adding any classes on scroll.

Comment: @tdrsam I have created another fiddle for you. Check out updated fiddle - another variant :-)

Comment: Yay. I finally got it. I never thought of using a second copy of the logo. Very clever.